# __FILE__ macro returns empty string

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I can't find a way to debug the current file name using preprocessor variables.
According to [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019#standard-predefined-macros) all I need is the standard predefined macro __FILE__, but when I tried it, it returns an empty string

I also found [this](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars) according to which the __FILE__ macro should return the name of the current file or empty string for the root file, but I can't really tell what's the difference between current and root file.

The rest of the predefined macros are working just as expected.

These two rows:

```
debug.Log("Time: " + __TIME__)
debug.Log("Filename: " + __FILE__)
```

Return

```
Time: 17:36:50
Filename:
```

I need them to return

```
Time: 17:36:50
Filename: filename.mrs
```

As you can see in the examples I shared, the line with __TIME__ returns exactly what I want. So do the other available preprocessor macros I've tried.

It's just __FILE__ that is returning an empty string and I can't figure out why.

Comment: which is your compiler ?

Comment: @melpomene Well structures can have members that are pointers to functions :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Fair enough, but I've never seen that technique seriously used outside of my own code. :-)

Comment: You can write `debug.Log("Filename: " __FILE__)` without `+` as `__FILE__` expands to a string literal and string literals are concatenated at compile-time.

Comment: @melpomene you are correct - this is not C. I was trying to tag c-preprocessor and the C-tag showed up. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Could you provide some details about which preprocessor you're using (the actual software product) and how exactly you invoke it? Thanks.